# Decimal.quantize rounding error

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, truncate

I've stumbled across an issue with the quantize method when using the Decimal datatype, it seems to be giving rounding errors:

```
Decimal('1.0055').quantize(Decimal('0.000')) # Should output 1.006
>> Decimal('1.006') # CORRECT output
Decimal('1.0045').quantize(Decimal('0.000')) # Should output 1.005
>> Decimal('1.004') # INCORRECT output
```

Why is it sometimes rounding up and sometimes rounding down?

Comment: In first case as `.0055` which is greater than `.0050` it is rounded to next nearest `.006`. In second case `.0045` which is less than `.0050` it is rounded to `.004`

Comment: Hi this doesn't actually answer why this is occurring, The same issue can be seen when testing 1.0065 and 1.0075.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr This is what's called [bankers' rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).**

The default rounding mode is

```
ROUND_HALF_EVEN (to nearest with ties going to nearest even integer)
```

which is exactly what you're seeing: ties between `4` and `5`, and between `5` and `6`, are going to the even numbers (`4` and `6` respectively).

If you want a different rounding mode, you need to specify it explicitly.

The choices are:

```
ROUND_CEILING (towards Infinity),
ROUND_DOWN (towards zero),
ROUND_FLOOR (towards -Infinity),
ROUND_HALF_DOWN (to nearest with ties going towards zero),
ROUND_HALF_EVEN (to nearest with ties going to nearest even integer),
ROUND_HALF_UP (to nearest with ties going away from zero), or
ROUND_UP (away from zero).
ROUND_05UP (away from zero if last digit after rounding towards zero would have been 0 or 5; otherwise towards zero)
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context

See the `rounding` argument to `quantize()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize

Comment: Perfect! This explains what is going on. Would adding one of these as a parameter give the output I was expecting above? Thanks

Comment: @ZakStucke: In fact, several would. You need to think about what should happen to exact halves and to negative numbers, and the choice will become clear.